# Create document processing OCR similar to Nanonets

Tags: python, flutter, dart, tensorflow

I want to implement a document text processing OCR in my flutter app. Most of the OCRs that I have seen can only read texts from images but cannot organize just the important information that is actually needed, E.G: Name, Lastname, Date of birth, Genre, etc. They can only read the whole thing. I discovered this page called "Nanonets" which does exactly what I need. You train the AI with images indicating only the data that you want and it works really well. The problem is that I cannot afford the pro plan, so I was wondering if there is an alternative way to create something similar by my own with maybe Tensorflow or another tool.

Here's the page if you wanna take a look to see what I mean: https://nanonets.com/

Answer (score 1):

in my opine, you can't handle OCR text in organised manner without AI trained models. most of the AI model api service paid until and unless you trained your own AI models for that.

`another way is you can  try to clean your OCR Text data using apply NLP Natural language processing (NLP).`However, it's not accurate as much as an AI trained model.

Apply `regex` and find `email, contacts` or pattern based data which we can easily `identify by regex & eliminate from your actual string` and apply NLP steps your self to get quick output.

few `NLP terms/Rules` and `how its work`:

1. `Sentence Tokenization` - dividing a string of written language into its component sentences. (string will split via punctuation mark)//. sentence boundary.
2. `Word Tokenization` - dividing a string of written language into its component words. (sentence will divide in to words to clean string).
3. `Stop words` - Stop words are words which are filtered out before or after processing of text to get accurate output. //remove irrelevant words like `and`, `the`, `a`

then apply other NLP terms like ...`Text Lemmatization and Stemming`,`again regex` to clean text again & `bag of words`, `TF-IDF` etc.

paid AI models & service for accurate result checkout this [link](https://pdf.abbyy.com/products/mobile/business-card-reader/en/) which you can use. they provide AI services like scanning visiting card, scan docs etc.